# Lusternik-Shnirelman using closed sets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The Lusternik-Shnirelman category $LS(X)$ of a space $X$ is defined as the minimal cardinality of a cover by open sets contractible in $X$.

I'm interested in the analogous notion for closed covers instead of open covers. I.e., I'm considering $LS_{closed}(X)$ to be the minimal cardinality of a cover by closed sets contractible in $X$.

Question: Is $$LS(X)=LS_{closed}(X)?$$
At least for closed manifolds?

Comment: if you take $X=\mathbb R^2\setminus\mathbb Q\times0$ then $LS_{closed}(X)=2$, but $LS(X)$ is not defined cause $X$ is not locally-contractible

Comment: Thanks. Is something known for the manifold's case?

Comment: Actually, I think this category has originally been introduced using closed sets. After some years for various reasons people started to stick with the open version. However there's still quite a lot of literature on the closed version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now found a reference for the manifold case. Proposition 4.3 of Rudyak-Schlenk paper http://members.unine.ch/felix.schlenk/Maths/Papers/lus.pdf proves equality $$LS(X)=LS_{closed}(X)$$
for all binormal ANR's.

(A space is binormal if its product with the interval is normal. An ANR is an absolute neighborhood retract. This class of spaces includes all simplicial complexes, hence all smooth manifolds.)